# AWS EKS RBAC - Certificate based Auth

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster, I would like to perform certificate-based authentication for `kubectl` client.

I have generated a CSR with:

```
openssl req -new -key developers.key -out developers.csr -subj "/CN=developers/O=company"
```

Uploaded the CSR according to [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) and approve the certificate with:

`kubectl certificate approve <certificate>`

I downloaded the `<certificate>.crt` file and used in the `kubeconfig` file as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}

clusters:
  - cluster:
  certificate-authority-data: <base64-CA>
  server: <cluster-endpoint>
  name: <cluster-name>

contexts:
 - context:
   cluster: <context-name>
   namespace: <namespace>
   user: developers
   name: developer-context

current-context: developer-context

users:
 - name: developers
 user:
#    token: <token>
client-certificate-data: <base64 of Kubernetes signed certificate>
client-key-data: <base64 of developers.key>
```

> Please bear with the indentations here. That's not the real issue.

But, I'm still not able to authenticate to the cluster says:

```
the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
```

OR

```
You must login to the cluster first.
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think your issue is that eks does not support certificate based authentication. It uses aws iam roles, as is explained very well in this article: https://itnext.io/how-does-client-authentication-work-on-amazon-eks-c4f2b90d943b